# Laravel and Intervention Image getSize() error

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention

I'm trying to integrate Intervention/Image into my laravel project to create a thumbnail upon uploading an image.

The image upload itself works fine, it doesn't seem to have any issue recognizing Intervention itself.

Below is the code block. The error seems to happen on the line with the save statement, I'm able to die and dump the contents of `$img` after it's set.

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$name = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time());
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName =  $name . '.' . $extension;
$file->move('./uploads/images/', $fileName);

$img = Image::make($file)->fit(300);
$img->save('/uploads/thumbnails/' . $name, 60, 'jpg');
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /private/var/folders/87/p5x7mgy914qg9ytf2zccc6q00000gn/T/php3lshFS
```

After some searching I've found that this *could* be related to file size upload limits, but I've altered my php.ini file (all of this is local btw) to accept 20MB files and the file I'm trying to upload is less than 100kb. I've also reset both php through homebrew and apache. Still getting the error.

Is there any glaringly obvious issues in my use of Intervention? I'll happily provide more info, this is in the store function in one of my controllers btw.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to reflect `$fileName` location (`/uploads/images`). Maybe `$file` still refers to old location of the file (which already moved)?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I do it like this:

```
    public function thumbnail(Request $request){
        $thumbDir= storage_path('app/public').'/uploads/thumbnails/';
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time()).'.jpg';
        // $name = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time());
        // $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // $fileName =  $name . '.' . $extension;
        // $file->move('./uploads/images/', $fileName);
        Image::make($file)->encode('jpg', 60)->fit(300, null, function ($c) {
            $c->aspectRatio();
            $c->upsize();
        })->save($thumbDir . $filename);
        return back()->with('success','The Image Has Been Added.');
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. Please click to accept it as the correct answer.